# How to create pivot table with huge dataset?

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a `txt` file that is 80 Mb . Tried import it to excel but it worked only partially. Not all datapoints were imported. I need to create pivot table. How can I do this ? Is there any way I could have this external connection to `txt` file that is on my computer and build a pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question is discribed in this articles: [1](http://exceluser.com/formulas/msquery-excel-text-files.htm) and [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.datamap/zf0U-zSeypQ). Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Which version of excel do you use? I guess Excel 2010 and 2013 should be able to handle the 80mb file. You could then try using [powerpivot](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel/download-powerpivot-HA101959985.aspx).